# How to clear the BIOS admin password in the standard case that you know the admin password? (no motherboard pw reset, just remove it in the BIOS)

Tags: bios, passwords

After creating a BIOS Administrator Password:

"Create New Password":

[image]

and confirming:

"Confirm New Password":

[image]

How do you clear this password so that you do not need to enter any password at BIOS startup anymore?

*PS: This is a very easy question. Strangely, it took me some time to find out since searching for this will give you many other more complex hits about forgotten passwords, but not the easy idea of just clearing the password when you know your current password.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do as if you entered the password the first time.

"Enter Current Password":

[image]

Then you can create an empty new password, just press Enter.

"Create New Password":

[image]

And press Enter again.

"Clear Old Password. Continue?":

[image]